# Threading in c# while making put calls

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am new to threading world of c#. I read there are different ways to do threading like sequential.

My scenario is below. Which one would be more suitable for the below.

I have list of complex objects. I will be making calls to PUT endpoint for each object [body of put] separately. There can be 1000 or more objects in the list. And I cannot pass all the objects at one and hence I have to pass each object in every call to the put endpoint. In this way, I have to make 1000 calls separately if there are 1000 objects.

Each put call is independent of each other while I have to store the properties of the response back from each call.

I was thinking to apply threading concept to above but not sure which one and how to do it.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanking in advance.

As per the comments below,
Putting the method signatures here and adding more details.

I have `IEnumerable<CamelList>`. For each camel, I have to make a put request call and update the table from the response of each call. I will write a new method that will accept this list and make use of below 2 methods to make call and update table. I have to ensure, I am making not more than 100 calls at the same time and the API I am calling can be called by the same user 100 times per minute.

We have a method as
`public Camel SendRequest(handler, uri, route, Camel); //basically takes all the parameters and provide you the Camel.`

We have a method as `public void updateInTable(Entity Camel); //updates the table.`

Comment: First, the earliest supported version of .NET is 4.5.2, where HTTP calls are made with `HttpClient`. Second, HttpClient's methods are *all* asynchronous, eg `HttpClient.PutAsync()` will run in the background. You don't need to use threading to make them run in the background. You could even write `myUrlObjectPairss.Select(data=>client.PutAsync(data.url,data.Content)).ToArray()` and start all calls in parallel

Comment: My bad. We are using c#6. I by mistakenly added the other  c#4 one.

Comment: @Vicky - Your types in the signatures you've added are not consistent. There is no way that this is your real code. Please, if you want help, make the effort to make it as easy for us to answer as possible. We need a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

HTTP calls are typically made using the [HttpClient class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client), whose HTTP methods are *already* asynchronous. You don't need to create your own threads or tasks.

All asynchronous methods return a `Task` or `Task<T> value. You need to use the`await`keyword to await for the operation to complete asynchronously - that means the thread is released until the operation completes. When that happens, execution resumes after the`await`.

You can see how to write a PUT request [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client#sending-a-put-request-to-update-a-resource). The example uses the [PutAsJsonAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclientextensions.putasjsonasync(v=vs.118).aspx) method to reduce the boilerplate code needed to serialize a `Product` class into a string and create a `StringContent` class with the correct content type, eg:

```
var response = await client.PutAsJsonAsync($"api/products/{product.Id}", product);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
```

If you want to PUT 1000 products, all you need is an array or list with the products. You can use LINQ to make multiple calls and await the tasks they return at the end :

```
var callTasks = myProducts.Select(product=>client.PutAsJsonAsync($"api/products/{product.Id}", product);
var responses =  await Task.WhenAll(callTasks);
```

This means that you have to wait for all requests to finish before you can check if any one succeeded. You can change the body of `Select` to await the response itself :

```
var callTasks = myProducts.Select(async product=>{
       var response=await client.PutAsJsonAsync($"api/products/{product.Id}", product);
       if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
       {
           //Log the error                  
       }
       return response.StatusCode;
});
var responses=await Task.WhenAll(callTasks);
```

It's better to conver the lambda into a separate method though, eg PutProductAsync :

```
async Task<HttpStatusCode> PutProduct(Product product,HttpClient client)
{
           var response=await client.PutAsJsonAsync($"api/products/{product.Id}", product);
           if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
           {
               //Log the error                  
           }
           return response.StatusCode;
 };

 var callTasks = myProducts.Select(product=>PutProductAsync(product));
 var responses=await Task.WhenAll(callTasks);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Panagiotis Kanavos. Only question is the api I am going to call or consume allows only 100 calls from a particular Id for a minute or so. In that case, would it be good to put a wait or thread.sleep for double the time for eg. 2 mins before making next 100 calls. I said double just considering some buffer time. Or is there any other better way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to suggest using Microsoft's Reactive Framework for this. You need to NuGet "System.Reactive" to get the bits.

Then you can do this:

```
var urls = new string[1000]; //somehow populated;

Func<string, HttpContent, IObservable<string>> putCall = (u, c) =>
    Observable
        .Using(
            () => new HttpClient(),
            hc =>
                from resp in Observable.FromAsync(() => hc.PutAsync(u, c))
                from body in Observable.FromAsync(() => resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync())
                select body);

var callsPerTimeSpanAllowed = 100;
var timeSpanAllowed = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1.0);

IObservable<IList<string>> bufferedIntervaledUrls =
    Observable.Zip(
        Observable.Interval(timeSpanAllowed),
        urls.ToObservable().Buffer(callsPerTimeSpanAllowed),
        (_, buffered_urls) => buffered_urls);

var query =
    from bufferedUrls in bufferedIntervaledUrls
    from url in bufferedUrls
    from result in putCall(url, new StringContent("YOURCONTENTHERE"))
    select new { url, result };

IDisposable subscription =
    query
        .Subscribe(
            x => { /* do something with each `x.url` & `x.result` */ },
            () => { /* do something when it is all finished */ });
```

This code is breaking the URLs into blocks (or buffers) of 100 and putting them on a timeline (or interval) of 1 minute apart. It then calls the `putCall` for each URL and returns the result.

It's probably a little advanced for you now, but I thought this answer might be useful just to see how clean this can be.

Comment: Thanks @Enigmativity. I am not familiar with system.reactive extension and hence I was reading about it. Seems like a good approach. But, my team is suggesting me to use Parallel.Foreach for threading which is again new to me. I am trying to see how I can implement that and the advantages and disadvantages to come up with the reason if it is not a good approach. Never applied both of them before. Let me know if you know how to implement it using parallel.foreach way. I might have to add a retry feature if there is any issue in the response apart from 401, 403 or some genuine status code.

Comment: @Vicky - You can't buffer by time with `Parallel.For`. You would need to break apart your original list of `urls` into blocks of 100 and put a timer around them - then you could use `Parallel.For`. You would still need to manage the timer and the grouping - which my code does easily.

Comment: Oh okay. makes sense. We already have a method for post where in I just have to pass as to type of object I expect in a response, url, httpClientHandler which returns me deserialized object. Also, once the response is received, I need to store some properties in azure table storage. How can I update above code to do that? Because, I see in ToObservable.Using(......); as some inbuilt method of IObservable interface.

Comment: @Vicky - You would really need to post a [mcve] to show me what you're doing. It's very difficult to get it right from a basic description of the code. Also, there's no `ToObservable.Using(......)` in my code, but I assume you mean just `Observable.Using(......)`. It's easy to replace that code. It's just a `Func<string, HttpContent, IObservable<YOURTYPE>>` that you'd need to write. But if you post the complete code I can help.

Comment: Updated the question with method signatures for more information.